# The best way to designate unsaturation (double bond)

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Although it has [already been explained here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94323/use-of-%CE%94-delta-to-describe-alkenes) that the use of the "Δ" (Greek capital delta) character is not recommended to designate unsaturation in individual names, [IUPAC 1989 Nomenclature of steroids](http://publications.iupac.org/pac/pdf/1989/pdf/6110x1783.pdf) states that it may be used, however, in generic terms, like "Δ<sup>5</sup>-steroids"; see note 3) on page 10. What are the current trends on whether should we continue or cease using the "Δ" symbol to describe a double bond per se (rather than in the name of a steroid) or just the position of such bond between consecutively numbered junctions, in various relevant compounds, not just steroids? Isn't it a concise and elegant way to denote such a bond, or is there a better, modern, suggested, clear way? Are there recommendations or best practices documents published on that, or research papers? For, example, instead of writing "steroids with a double bond between carbon 5 and 6 junctions" we could simply write "Δ<sup>5</sup>-steroids", an example given in the note 3) on page 10 of the UIPAC Nomenclature of steroids of 1989? Here is such an example in practice, in a 2020 publication (quote): ["couple of Δ<sup>5</sup>-steroids with hydroxyl group at C3 position"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33157220/). Can we just use the "Δ" symbol to describe the position of the double bond e.g. "3βHSD isomerizes the double bond from the Δ<sup>5</sup> to the Δ<sup>4</sup> position" or just (quote): ["Δ5 → Δ4 isomerization by 3βHSD"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21030877/)? Or should we cease the use of the double-bond position as a common denominator in favor of other similarities in a group of compounds, e.g. "3-keto-steroids" instead of "Δ<sup>4</sup>-steroids" or "3-hydroxy-steroids" instead of "Δ<sup>5</sup>-steroids"?

Comment: As you care of these things, "HSD3B2 isomerizes the double bond from the Δ5 to the Δ4 position"? does not tell anything clear. Moreover 5,6 to 4,3 position is also a common possibility (and doesn't require special character).